# Unable to insert new data into database via PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I am unable to store new data into the database after the user submits the form. I check the database table via phpMyAdmin, but I do not see any new data. Can anyone show me the mistake in my code.

**HTML code** (listing.html):

```
<html>
    <form action="confirm_listing.php" method="POST">
        <input name="Firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
        <input name="Lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

**php code** (confirm_listing.php):

```
<?php
    $firstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['Lastname'];
    $address = $_POST['Address'];
    $suburb = $_POST['Suburb'];
    $city = $_POST['City'];
    $type = $_POST['Type'];
    $room = $_POST['Room'];
    $floorArea = $_POST['Floor'];
    $landArea = $_POST['Land'];
    $price = $_POST['Price'];
    $contact = $_POST['Contact'];
    $active = "1";

    $server = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname = "summitrealestatedb";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

    if (!$connection) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO property (firstname, lastname, address, suburb, city, type, room, floor, land, price, contact, active) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$address', '$suburb', '$city', '$type', '$room', '$floorArea', '$landArea', '$price', '$contact', '$active');";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Here is [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfjjZ.jpg) of what it currently looks like in the database table:

[image]

Comment: You need to protect against SQL injections and use `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Devon Yes Devon thanks for that, i will make use of that once i can get it to store any data at all.

Comment: @JeffSloyer I don't get any error from my code, i just don't understand why it does not store any data into the database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print error of insert

```
 mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: Gojinetchi Thats a really neat way for debugging this, i got an error as follow "Champ 'type' inconnu dans field list"

Comment: @smuhero That's because there is no field `type` in your table.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually found out that as well and a wee bit too late.

Comment: Before making the insert, you need to do validation on fields(isset,no sql inject etc.)
 And dont forget if string have " ' " will insert sql error

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
<?php
    $firstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['Lastname'];
?>
```

use

```
<?php
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
?>
```

use the name that you have assigned to the name not to the placeholder

Comment: @Akshay Vasu sorry, Akshay that is correct i had misentered.

Comment: @smuhero thats ok. if this answer have worked for you , accept this one by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: @AkshayVasu Unfortunately, i have made a type it during asking a question submission. It had the exact same capital Firstname and Lastname in my original code.